# Butler is to Jeeves as Maid is to

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to see if there a term for a maid that equates to the use of the word Jeeves for a butler. It is an if, I'm not sure there is one, after Jeeves is only the joking name for a butler due to the Jeeves and Wooster books (as far as I know it).

Is there a maid equivalent? Or even a non-gendered version? Maybe for a generic home-help kind of role?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61969/discussion-on-question-by-puffafish-butler-is-to-jeeves-as-maid-is-to).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In earlier centuries, the word would be Abigail, but I don't think many people would understand it now.

The OED says:

> Now *arch.* and *hist.*
>       A lady's maid; a female servant or attendant.

Comment: There is no equivalence of position between a butler and a lady's maid. It would be valet and lady's maid. I should have thought you might have picked up on that....

Comment: Neither Puffafish nor I have suggested there was an equivalence of position. What has that to do with anything?

Comment: @Lambie Also, Jeeves-the-character was actually a gentleman's gentleman, AKA a valet. To a lot of us heathen colonials, all them fancy-schmancy oppressed serving folk are basically the same thing ;-).

Comment: @1006a Oh, heathen colonials. Like they don't have servants......

Comment: Some good answers, but I think this is the closest I'm going to get. Seems like the real answer is; there isn't one that would be understood by anyone.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of such a word for a maid, but a cleaning lady or home-help might be a ***[Mrs Mop](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/Mrs_Mop)***

> Mrs Mop (also Mrs Mopp) NOUN
>
> British  (A nickname for) a charwoman, a cleaning lady. 
> Origin 1940s.
> From the name of a charwoman in the BBC radio comedy series I.T.M.A
> (‘It's that Man Again’), broadcast from 1941 to 1945.
>
> — [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/Mrs_Mop)

Comment: "cleaning lady of home"?? Jeeves is certainly not a cleaning man. There is  no equivalence between a Jeeves and a charwoman. Banish the thought.

Comment: The question didn't ask for equivalence between jeeves and a charwoman, and I have not provided one. The question asked for 'a term for a maid that equates to the use of the word Jeeves for a butler' and allowed that a term for a home-help might do. Thank you for pointing out my typing error.

Comment: A Jeeves is a butler, a man who served at table. There is no female in the same category at all. In any event, there is a housekeeper and housemaids (who did the cleaning). I was not pointing out a typing error but rather the odd phrasing. You did in fact say A is to B as C is to D.

Comment: @Lambie No-ne has claimed that Jeeves char or that female servants wait at table. I did indeed say 'A is to B, and C is to D'. Where A is 'a Jeeves' and B is a butler, D is a maid and we are seeking a term to fill the gap at C. There is nothing in that which attempts to say A=C or B=D.

Comment: @Lambie You've got me confused now. *I* didn't say A is to B etc, the OP did. The only edit I have made to my answer is to correct 'of' to 'or'.

Answer (score 2):

[Hazel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazel_(comics)) was probably the best-known maid in mid-20th century America. In addition to the comic strip, there was also a TV show in the 1960s.

Still, nowhere near as universally known as Wodehouse's Jeeves.

Comment: Was 'Hazel' used as a byword for 'maid' in the way that 'jeeves' apparently is for 'butler'?

Comment: No, not nearly to the extent that Jeeves was, and certainly not as a single word (e.g., "Home, Jeeves"*) but "Hazel the maid" was a common trope.

* - Jeeves was even less a chauffeur than he was a butler, but it's still a common usage...

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand where chauffeurs came into this...

Comment: "Home, Jeeves" is usually (somewhat sarcastically) directed to a driver.

Comment: Isn't that 'Home, James, and don't spare the horses'? I've never heard 'Home, jeeves'. https://idiomation.wordpress.com/2014/01/13/dont-spare-the-horses/

Comment: Maybe "Home Jeeves" is an Americanism; it's certainly better known here (there's even a [transport service](http://www.homejeevesdrivers.com/) with that name). I've not heard "Home, James, etc." before, but it's well-attested by Google.

Comment: Sounds like the gentleman's gentleman branched out when he got stateside!

Comment: American here - I've never heard "Home, Jeeves" before this thread. "Home, James" I'm familiar with.

Comment: Hazel came to my mind, too, but largely because it's a name that is suddenly becoming popular with the baby-naming set...much to the surprise of their mothers and grandmothers, who think of it as a "maid's name".